# Code to delete Excel sheets is not working

Tags: c#-4.0

I have written the following code to delete the Excel sheets from the Excel workbook. The code is not throwing any error but is on opening the Excel the sheets are not deleted.

```
 public void EXcelCleanup(string Excelpath)
 {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            string WorkbookLocation = Excelpath;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(WorkbookLocation,
            0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
            true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets worksheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

            int wsCount = worksheets.Count;

            if (wsCount > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 2; i <wsCount-1; i++)
                {
                    worksheets[i].Delete();
                }
            }

            excelWorkbook.Save();
            excelWorkbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets);
            excelApp.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of pointers.

1. With .Net 4.0 you have optional parameters, so you probably dont need to provide all the arguments to open a spreadsheet.
2. Delete the sheets in a reverse loop:

   `for (int i = wsCount-1; wsCount-1 > 1; i--)  worksheets[i].Delete();`
3. You dont need the `if (wsCount > 1)` as the loop has this condition.
4. Set the `excelWorkbook.Saved = true;` right before the `excelWorkbook.Save();` to avoid excel prompting you to save.
5. Check you are not opening the spreadsheet in readonly mode.

Comment: I think yes the file may be in readonly mode during the execution of this code so what to add before the execution of this code to make it not readonly.

Comment: hey I got my answer need to close the workbook before this code. Thanks :)